# Getting response code 401 causes skipping code blocks

Tags: angularjs, authentication, response, skip

I'm writing an ionic v1/express/mongo/node app. When checking if the user is authenticated i have the following piece of code:

```
checkAuthentication: function(token) {
            console.log(token);
            return $http.get("http://validUrl/test", {
                headers: {
                    'testingAuth': token
                }
            }).then(function(result) {
                return result.data;
            });
        }
```

and am calling it like this:

```
checkAuthentication(token).then(function(response) {
            console.log("testing response: " + response);
            // if a valid token is already in storage = response contains "Success"(?), just $state.go to main page, else call the login() function
            if (response.content === "Success") {
                // $state.go main page
            } else {
                console.log("could not log in");
            }
        })
```

The problem is, when I get back code 401 from the server, I somehow skip the then block in the checkAuthentication function. Execution doesn't stop at a breakpoint at "return result.data", or "console.log("could not log").

Am I doing something obviously wrong? Is there something i need to do to force going into that block? Thanks for any advice.

Comment: add the error handler to your get request and see if it provides any insight like so https://jsfiddle.net/ojzdxpt1/23/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with your error handling ! I took the liberty to modify your code and the way to do a $http call. Here is the working [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/XEjjMdqpDm9ltPGLSqDl) for the same.

If you observe the `$scope.login()` function I've injected the service object and invoked the `checkAuthentication()` function which does the HTTP call.As you are using `.then` for http calls, angular provides provision to use two functions for success and error callbacks where your HTTP errors go when HTTP calls fail.

Here is the angular [doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) for the same.

In your example you don't have error callback method hence it doesn't go into your if else conditions.

```
var app = angular.module("App", []);
app.controller('AppCtrl', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$http', 'Service', function($rootScope, $scope, $http, Service) {


  $scope.login = function(token) {
  //call the injected service in the function for HTTP call..
    Service.checkAuthentication(token).then(function(response) {
      console.log("testing response: " + response);
      // if a valid token is already in storage = response contains "Success"(?), just $state.go to main page, else call the login() function
      if (response.content === "Success") {
        // $state.go main page
      } 
    },function(error){
      console.log(error);
      console.log("could not log in due to error...");
    });
  };


}]);
//use angular services to do a http call for better code maintainability...
app.service('Service', ['$http', '$rootScope', function($http, $rootScope) {

  return {
    checkAuthentication: function(token) {
      return $http.get("http://validUrl/test", {
        headers: {
          'testingAuth': token
        }
      });
    }
  };
}]);
```

Comment: Yep, was even reading that docs page but somehow missed it. Thank you.